# Error that invalid SMS code was entered, while it's actually valid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using FirebaseAuth phone, when code entered sometime go success, sometimes show me code invalid with error message, and sometimes go into successful and invalid at the same time how I don't know.

```
private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        mAuth!!.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this@VerificationPhoneActivity, object : OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> {
                override fun onComplete(task: Task<AuthResult>) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // val user = task.getResult().getUser()
                        val user: String = task.result?.user?.uid.toString()
                        //   val isNew:Boolean = task.result?.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser
                        callApi(user)
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        var message: String = "Somthing is wrong, we will fix it soon..."
                        if (task.getException() is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            message = "Invalid code entered...";
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

as I make toast it show me invalid or this error message from firebase where the SMS code is valid.

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalididCredentilalsException:“The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.”

Comment: Post your logcat if you get any.

Comment: i print  task.getException().toString(), which show this msg . com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalididCredentilalsException:“The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.”

Comment: Well, it says that your id token has expired. You need to re-authenticate.

Comment: ya , but i recived at same time, its not be more than second , why show me invalid?